# JS DOMNode checkbox set value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-node

I'm using HTML template tags to render content via JS (no jQuery or anything else).

Using `content.cloneNode(true)` to clone the nodes, set the content, values, ... and at the end I append it to a node inside the HTML. Thats working fine for every element so far. But currently I have an issue with input type checkbox. I can't set the value. (I don't mean the checked status)

The problem is, when I set the value it's not part of the HTML element thats getting rendered. Not visible with the browser dev tools and also `document.querySelector(...).value` will return an empty string.

My goal is to be able to fetch on a button click the values of all enabled (checked) checkboxes for an AJAX request.

Code example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3gnLv67x/

Comment: can u actually provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @ericmp yes here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9zyamfL8/

If you change the value in the template it will show it in the validate div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the reason why the value is not getting set. But since it's only a simple input field I changed to the code to create the element instead of using a template for that.

This way is working.

```
const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = 'selected[]';
checkbox.className = 'select-box';
checkbox.value = item.id;
```

I'm still up to hear a solution how to get that working with templates.